# xaml DependencyProperty autocomplete issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a behavior for Textbox:

```cs
// C#
  public class DigitsOnlyBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDigitOnlyProperty =
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDigitOnly",
     typeof(bool), typeof(DigitsOnlyBehavior),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsDigitOnlyChanged));

    public static bool GetIsDigitOnly(Control obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsDigitOnlyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsDigitOnly(Control obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsDigitOnlyProperty, value);
    }

private static void OnIsDigitOnlyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ignoring error checking
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var isDigitOnly = (bool)(e.NewValue);

        if (isDigitOnly)
            textBox.PreviewTextInput += BlockNonDigitCharacters;
        else
            textBox.PreviewTextInput -= BlockNonDigitCharacters;
    }
}
```

In xaml I do this:

```
<!-- XAML -->
 <TextBox local:DigitsOnlyBehavior.IsDigitOnly="true" />
```

Question is why I must to type string false or true, instead choose from list False or True like for let's say IsEnabled property? It's possible to change that?